# Parsing this sentence

Tags: grammar

The speaker has just started his new job at a bakery and one of his co-workers is worried that he is being asked to do something that is too dangerous for newcomers by one of his other co-workers.

Person a「もう……新人だからって何でも言うこと聞くのは間違っていると思います。新人に窯出しは危険ですよ」

Person b「でも、下手に他の作業やっても場が混乱するからさ。最初は言われたとおりにやるしかないって」

Person a「私、体育会系のノリって嫌いなんです。根性だけで何でも済ませてたらいつか大ケガするじゃないですか」

Person b「でもメガネくん、あれで一応俺には気を使ってくれているみたいでさ」

Person b **「オーブンを触るときは、大声出してるときでもちゃんと見ててくれるんだよ」**

Person a「先輩って、変な人ですね。私なら仕事でもあれだけ言われたら怒ります」

Person b「大丈夫、適度に言い返してガス抜きしてるから」

I am not sure how to parse the bolded sentence of this exchange, and the subjects of the individuals parts. I think that the subject of オーブンを触る is the speaker, and ちゃんと見ててくれる is メガネくん, however I am not sure for 大声出してる. Part of what is confusing me is that there are two occurrences of とき. Is the following the correct way to understand this sentence:

When I'm touching the oven, he watches me properly, even when he is shouting/raising his voice.

Comment: It is unclear who says what. [Context with a specified source](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important) would help.

Answer (score 1):

> When I'm touching the oven, he watches me properly, even when he is shouting/raising his voice.

I don't know who メガネくん is (it can be person A or the other person C), but yes, I agree with your thought. Person A says "私なら仕事でもあれだけ言われたら怒ります", so they're definitely talking about someone else (person C).

> オーブンを触るときは、大声出してるときでもちゃんと見ててくれるんだよ

The second とき is also confusing to me. As your English sentence indicates, he should have watched person A first and then scolded A with a loud voice. It's kind of weird that to scold A with a loud voice and to watch A occur at exact the same time. While I can understand what it means, it's not very logical.

I'd say like these:

「オーブンを触るときは、大声こそ出してるけどちゃんと見ててはくれるんだよ」

「オーブンを触るときは、ちゃんと見ててくれるんだよ。たまに大声で注意されるけど」